# Rotate and duplicate row values in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I'm trying to rotate values in a sheet and then duplicate the first value in the row as a header. For example:

```
a | b | c | d
```

would become:

```
a | b
-----
a | c
-----
a | d
```

Is there any way to do this with just Google Sheets commands, or do I need to use a script?

Comment: can you provide larger sample of example?

Comment: @user0 Sure, did that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(
 TRANSPOSE("♥"&A1&"♦"&B1:D1), , 999^99), "♥")), "♦")))
```

[image]

Comment: Wow! I'm still trying to wrap my head around how this works, but using ♥ and ♦ as delimiters was a neat trick! Very fast solution as well! Would you mind explaining how the blank query works?

Comment: blank query is an alternative to JOIN or TEXTJOIN which are limited to join only 50000 characters. this "query smush" is pretty much limitless (can process 999^99 (= 9.05698E+296) rows of data)

Comment: After picking this apart, I came up with `=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE("♥"&A1&"♦"&B1:D1), "♦♥", TRUE))`, which seems more efficient. Are there any issues with this solution?

Comment: nah, that would work too for one row. however, it's not scalable so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YumzC.png